# C# - How do I set NULL to an instance method that cannot be NULL?

Tags: c#, null, click, menuitem

**How do I set NULL to an instance method that cannot be NULL?**

Error message: Der Delegat einer Instanzenmethode kann kein "this" von NULL haben.

The problem is, that I have a method creating a MenuItem click event to run anything. But in one case there is no click event needed, so I need to set the parameter to NULL. C# does not like that. Do you know why?

```
public MenuItem SetMenuitem(string IconSource, RoutedEventHandler Click, string Header, string IGT, string Name)
    {
        Image Icon = new Image();
        Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(IconSource, UriKind.Relative));
        Icon.Height = 16;
        Icon.Width = 16;
        Icon.Stretch = Stretch.None;

        MenuItem MenuItem = new MenuItem();
        MenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Click);
        MenuItem.Header = Header;
        MenuItem.Icon = Icon;
        MenuItem.InputGestureText = IGT;
        MenuItem.Name = Name;
        MenuItem.Padding = new Thickness(5);

        return MenuItem;
    }
```

Here is an example, where the second parameter is set to null cuz a click event is not needed:

```
MI_Layout = SetMenuitem(@"IMAGES\icon.png", null, MI_Layout_Header, null, MI_Layout_Name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a check for your `Click` parameter

```
if(Click != null)
 MenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Click);
```

Personally, there is something wrong with the design if you are passing in the required parameters for the Click event, I would define an Action to attach it on the calling method.

Comment: Because the easiest way of solving a problem mostly seems to be too simple to think of. Thank you, it helped to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should just make another function of the same name that doesn't include the parameter and then doesn't set the click event. Instead of passing in NULL, call this function instead.

Example:

```
public MenuItem SetMenuitem(string IconSource, string Header, string IGT, string Name)
{
    Image Icon = new Image();
    Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(IconSource, UriKind.Relative));
    Icon.Height = 16;
    Icon.Width = 16;
    Icon.Stretch = Stretch.None;

    MenuItem MenuItem = new MenuItem();
    MenuItem.Header = Header;
    MenuItem.Icon = Icon;
    MenuItem.InputGestureText = IGT;
    MenuItem.Name = Name;
    MenuItem.Padding = new Thickness(5);

    return MenuItem;
}
```